# Read xml tag/value of testNG.xml suite while running

Tags: selenium, testng

If we are running TestNG via TestNG.xml 
Is there any way we can read loaded xml tag like "thread-Count" in program

`<suite name="Grid Parallel Test Suite" verbose="3" preserve-order="false" parallel="methods" thread-count="1">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what does the "program" mean here, I suppose you mean the tests being run by TestNG.

If that's the case this can be done by accessing the test content in test listener class.

a. Create test listener class which extends TestListenerAdapter, the suite attributes can be get from ITestContext. For example:

```java
    public class SomeTestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
       /**
        * When the suite started.
        * @param testContext Test context
        */
        public final void onStart(final ITestContext testContext) {
            XmlSuite suite = testContext.getSuite().getXmlSuite();
        // Get thread count        
            int threads = suite.getThreadCount();
        // Get preserve order setting
        String order = suite.getPreserveOrder();
        // Get parallel attribute
        String parallel = suite.getParallel();
            // Do something
            super.onStart(testContext);
        }
    }
```

b. Add the class as listeners in testng.xml or by other ways. TestNG document already has details:  http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners

Comment: lovely ,though i figured it out but thanks for posting the solution, just one question though silly , but what does this super.onStart does, do i require this while writting the Listner

Comment: @kapilA super.onStart just call the original method in super listener class to make sure we don't miss anything. I think it's a good habit to do so. However in this case, I found that in org.testng.TestListenerAdapter actually the onStart, onFinish, onTestStart methods are empty. However the other methods do have content. You can see more from [TestListenerAdapter.java on Github](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/TestListenerAdapter.java)